# Como imprimir um ArrayAdapter customizado em um fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou utilizando um menu Drawer na minha aplicação Android e preciso imprimir uma lista no fragment ao clicar no item do menu lateral, como crio um ArrayAdapter customizado e como o invoco no fragment?

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Essa pergunta é um pouco aberta, há várias formas de se fazer isso, e a existência de um Drawer não é tão relevante, de qualquer forma, aqui está um link em português: http://blog.alura.com.br/criando-uma-lista-com-listview-no-android/